# Python Resize Images

Tags: python-3.x, image, tensorflow, resize, image-recognition

I have a data set containing over 10,000 images of dogs. I plan to use tensorflow to classify dog breeds, however the images are random sizes. For example, some are 200x280 pixels, 100x140 pixels, etc. I would like to standardize the images so that they are smaller and all the same dimensions. Is this possible? I realize it will skew the images, but that is not a huge concern. I just need to be able to build a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Tensorflow image resizing docs.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image#Resizing)

It's also worth noting that you don't have to resize the images with Tensorflow. You could do it as a preprocessing step with OpenCV. Whether you do it with Tensorflow comes down the usual tradeoffs between doing preprocessing in or outside the graph (if you do it in the graph, one less step when you are serving predictions, but it also makes the graph more computationally expensive to train, among other tradeoffs).